# Function in java

Tags: java

I am making return type functions to encrypt some string

My code is

```
public String encrypt(char x)
{
    String enc = "";
    switch(x)
    {
        case 'A' : enc = "B";
        break;
        case 'a' : enc = "x";
        break;
        case 'B' : enc = "C";
        break;
        case 'b' : enc = "w";
        break;
        case 'C' : enc = "D";
        break;
        case 'c' : enc = "v";
        break;
        case 'D' : enc = "E";
        break;
        case 'd' : enc = "u";
        break;
        case 'E' : enc = "F";
        break;
        case 'e' : enc = "t";
        break;
        case 'F' : enc = "G";
        break;
        case 'f' : enc = "s";
        break;
    }
    return(enc);
}

public String encryptString(String input)
{
    String Encryption = "";
    int length = input.length();
    int charVal = 0;
    for (charVal = 0; charVal<=length;charVal++)
    {
        char encChar = input.charAt(charVal);
        String encrypted = encrypt(encChar);
        Encryption = Encryption+encrypted+"";
    }
    return (Encryption);
}
```

I am unable to use `encryptString()` with JOptionPane's `showInputDialog()`.

Comment: What do you mean you aren't unable to use the function? Does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (charVal = 0; charVal<=length;charVal++)
```

should be

`for (charVal = 0; charVal<length;charVal++)`

otherwise `input.charAt(charVal);` will throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` for the last iteration.

But you could make your code more efficient using a `StringBuilder` :

```
public String encryptString(String input){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : input.toCharArray())
            sb.append(encrypt(c));
        return sb.toString();
}
```

Few notes :

- The return type of your `encrypt(char x)` method could be `char`
- Be aware that `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` returns `null` if the user canceled the input